# Swift array of generic closures?

Tags: ios, generics, swift, closures, type-constraints

Is it possible? The error `Only syntatic function types can be generic` suggests it isn't.

**Valid Code**

```
func test<T:Equatable>(function: (T) -> T){
    var myArray:Array<T -> T> = [function];
}
```

Now I want to make a property with the same type as `myArray`. I feel like I should be able to do this somehow.

**Doesn't work**

`var myArray:<T:Equatable>(T -> T)[]`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even this:

```
func test<T:Equatable>(function: (T) -> T){
    var myArray:Array<T -> T> = function;
}
```

Shouldn't be valid. You are assigning a `T->T` to a `Array<T->T>`. It should be at least:

```
var myArray:Array<T -> T> = [function];
```

This would work:

```
class MyClass<T> {

    var myArray:(T->T)[] = []

}
```

Since you now have a generic MyClass class, to initialise, you need to tell what type `T` is, like so:

```
var x = MyClass<String>()
```

Comment: Yes that was a typo, I fixed it. `var myArray:(T->T)[] = []` has the error `Use of undeclared type T` which is why you need to use type constraints

Comment: I added it to `myClass<T>`